# I keep on getting an error relating to my hash

Tags: ruby

I made a hash on **Repl.it**, and I've tried everything but I keep getting the same error.

I've done more research on hashes and I've learnt a lot. I'm fourteen and I've already run into a mojor problem on ruby 2.5.5.

This is the hash I made

```
name_hash {15 => "Michael", 13 =>"Christopher",114 =>"Ryan"
```

The expected result is to have no errors but I just come back with this error

```
(repl):9: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
name_hash {15 => "Michael", 13 =>"Christopher...
              ^~
(repl):9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
name_hash {15 => "Michael", 13 =>"Christopher",114 =>"Ry...
```

Comment: You forgot the trailing } and the assignment operator =.

Comment: Off-topic because : "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
name_hash = {15 => "Michael", 13 =>"Christopher",114 =>"Ryan"}
```